# antlr same type arithmetic expression

Tags: math, types, expression, antlr

Trying to write a antlr grammar that parse the arithmetic expression for only same typed variable. If it is not a same type as left or right side, it should not be parse. This is what I have;

```
stat
    :   Left = VARIABLE Op = ASSIGMENT Right = expr     # Assigment
    ;

expr
    :   '('   Exp = expr ')'                            # Parens
    |   MINUS Exp = expr                                # UnaryMinus
    |   Left = expr Op = (TIMES | DIV)  Right = expr    # MulDiv
    |   Left = expr Op = (PLUS  | MINUS) Right = expr   # AddSub
    |   (VARIABLE | CONSTANT)                           # Element
    ;

ASSIGMENT   :   '=' ;
PLUS        :   '+' ;
MINUS       :   '-' ;
TIMES       :   '*' ;
DIV         :   '/' ;
LPAREN      :   '(' ;
RPAREN      :   ')' ;
```

I don't want anything like x = 5 + 'f' or x = c - 5, (if c is variable that is not integer)

Comment: You can't enforce that kind of constraint in the grammar. You'd check these things in the type checker, not the parser.

Answer (score 1):

It's called [Semantic analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_analysis_(compilers)).

When parsing is done you have to walk through the generated [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) and check correctness of each expression and variable.